# Why am I getting this error: "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"?

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to find the mean of this column in the data set, however, it is displaying a warning and not giving me the results.

**Here is the code I have tried:**

```
mean(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration)
```

**and this is the warning message I get back:**

```
>[1] NA
>Warning message:
>In mean.default(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration) :
>argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Can you check the `class(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration)`.  If the column is not numeric, `mean` won't work i.e `mean(c('a', 'b', 'c'))` also gives the same warniing

Comment: @akrun ok I just checked the data set in the console and for that column it says `<chr>` , so what should I do in this case?

Comment: iif you have a column like `v1 <- c('1', '3', '5')` with quotes, convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` `mean(as.numeric(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration))` you may get some warniing if there are some non-numeric elements

Comment: @akrun yes I get this warning now: `In mean(as.numeric(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: that is expected if you have some character elements

Comment: @akrun but I just said earlier that this column is of `character` data type

Comment: `mean(c('1', '2', 'a'))`

Comment: @akrun and how can I remove them?

Comment: the warning is just a friendly one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mean(as.numeric(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I get this warning: `Warning message:
In mean(as.numeric(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration), na.rm = TRUE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: This means that none of the items in the column are numeric (or all of them are NAs). Check the column values.